# Core plot:disabling pinches

Tags: ios, core-plot

Hi I am using core plot to plot reports.I want to disable pinches on the graphs,I have placed a slider on graph so i Cannot disable user interaction as slider will not work.Can anyone tell me how to disable pinches on graph hosting view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `allowPinchScaling` to NO on the hosting view.

Comment: Thank you Eric Skroch.I set the hosting view pinches to NO as mentioned by you

Answer (score -1):

if you already have put a gesture recognizer, to move the slider, you can use the

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

method. Then you have to specify the delegate of the Gesture Recognizer. In that method you can return either if you want to accept the touch or not.